# Functions, one-to-one

Tags: discrete-mathematics

we have to prove or disprove that the function is a)one to one b) f is an onto function c)if f is a one-to-one correspondent

1)F:Z→E, where Z is set of integers and E is set of even integers, be defined by the rule f(x) = 2x-2.

So what I understand is that a one to one function is if f(a) = f(b). Can anyone help me to approach this problem or how if you can show me how to disprove or prove this function is a good explanation, thank you

Comment: You understand incorrectly. Read again.

Answer (score 1):

For (a) For $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ assumme $f(a)=f(b)$. To show that $f$ is one-to-one we need to show that $f(a)=f(b)$ implies $a=b$. We have that $$f(a)=f(b) \Rightarrow 2a-2=2b-2 \Rightarrow 2a=2b \Rightarrow a=b$$
so $f$ is one-to-one.

For (b) The exercise says that the function goes from $\mathbb{Z}$ to the **even** numbers. So take an even number $k$. Then does there exist a $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(x)=k$? That is $$2x-2=k \Rightarrow x=\frac{k}{2}+1$$ but since $k$ is even then $k=2n$ for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. So $$x=\frac{2n}{n}+1=n+1 \in \mathbb{Z}$$ which means that $f$ is onto.

For (c) A [one-to-one correspondence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) or bijection is a function that is one-to-one and onto. So c) follows from a) and b).

Comment: for a) so would my function be considered one to one? Because isn't a an even number and b an odd number? Or do you just set a=b and find to see if f(a) = f(b)?

Comment: No, I set $f(a)=f(b)$ and find that $a=b$. Odd, even does not play a role in a. You cannot assume that f in one to one. That is exactly which you want to show, so you do not assume it. Is it clear?

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

a) Is it possible for $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ where $x_1 \ne x_2$? If so, then it is not one-to-one.

b) Given any even integer $n$, is there an integer $x$ such that $f(x)=n$? If so, it is onto.

c) If (a) and (b) are true, then $f$ is one-to-one correspondent.

Comment: a) so would my function be considered one to one? Because isn't a an even number and b an odd number? Or do you just set a=b and find to see if f(a) = f(b)?